How to add more than one controller node in EKS cluster
I am very new to this concept, so I was curious to know if we can create more than one controller node in EKS cluster or not. if yes how can we do so? Also, if not, how HA/fault tolerance is achieved in this kind of setup in the case of the control plane?
I just learned from a few videos on YouTube that we can have only one master node and can have node groups. so wanted to know how an organization achieves this HA while using EKS for their applications.

If you are using EKS, your control plane will always be multiple node, but this is not visible in your account. The choice you have is cluster in a single Zone or a whole Region (for HA/fault tolerance).


EKS architecture is designed to eliminate any single points of failure
that may compromise the availability and durability of the Kubernetes
control plane. The Kubernetes control plane managed by EKS runs inside
an EKS managed VPC. The EKS control plane comprises the Kubernetes API
server nodes, etcd cluster. Kubernetes API server nodes that run
components like the API server, scheduler, and kube-controller-manager
run in an auto-scaling group. EKS runs a minimum of two API server
nodes in distinct Availability Zones (AZs) within in AWS region.
Likewise, for durability, the etcd server nodes also run in an
auto-scaling group that spans three AZs. EKS runs a NAT Gateway in
each AZ, and API servers and etcd servers run in a private subnet.
This architecture ensures that an event in a single AZ doesn’t affect
the EKS cluster's availability.

So in short eks control plane is HA/fault tolerant. And as control plane component is managed by eks you would not be able to add or remove controller nodes.
https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/reliability/docs/controlplane/#eks-architecture
